# Escape % for ffprobe in batch (-read_intervals)

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, ffprobe

Maybe it will be a ridiculous question...
I've been looking around for 3 hours how to get the batch to run the ffprobe command without randomly expanding `%` inside the `-read_intervals` command.

Batch:

```
for %%a in ("*.mkv") do ffprobe -read_intervals 1%16 -v error -skip_frame nokey -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time -select_streams v -of csv=p=0 -i "%%a" >> KFS.txt
```

It would be the basic command. However `1%16` is seen as `%1`. Even putting `1%%16` or `1%%%16` continues to expand the `%1`. I tried any combination with `("" '' @ ^)` read [this](https://sodocumentation.net/batch-file/topic/10693/escaping-special-characters) link 10 times (and many more).
The command on normal Windows CMD works fine. It is its batch conversion that gives problems.

`-read_intervals` use `x%x` as the interval system.

Thanks in advance to those who explain me how to solve.

Comment: `1%%16` _should_ work.

Comment: No, I also wrote it. But I solved it right now.
Thanks anyway for the reply.

Comment: Please post your solution as your own answer, see [answer].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that "`_intervals`" was an additional command, so I found that you can use (**only in my specific case**) as input "`%%+6`" which means "**read only the first 6 seconds**".